# Cauchy Residue Theorem Application

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm a bit rusty on my complex integration, I'm trying to solve $\int(z+1)/(2z^3-3z^2-2z)dz$ over the unit circle.

By partial fractions I have $(z+1)/(2z^3-3z^2-2z)$ = $3/(10(z-2)) - 1/2z  +2/5(1+2z)$

Now, for the first fraction I got residue 3/10, for the second clearly -1/2, but for the third I'm having trouble. The solution to this is supposed to be -3/10.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $$\frac{2}{5(1+2z)} = \frac{1}{5\bigl(z+\frac{1}{2}\bigr)}$$ (Note that one of the singularities lies outside the unit disk.)

Comment: Isn't the only singularity at $z=-1/2$, inside |z|<1?

Comment: I meant "one of the singularities of the whole integrand".

Comment: Ahh of course... so the first fraction is analytic, and the other two give me -1/2 + 1/5 = -3/10 residues.

Thanks 

Edit: I'm new to the website and don't know how to make your comment an answer (or if I should) or how to give you credit for your help.

Comment: Writing an answer was good. After two days, you can accept your own answer, thus clearly indicating that the question has got a satisfactory answer (answers by other people can be accepted sooner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer pointed out, the residue of the first fraction inside the unit disc is zero, since it is analytic for $|z|<2$. The other two fractions have residues $-1/2$ and $1/5$ respectively, which add up to $-3/10$.